# Connection refused error in bitbucket pipeline with Docker library

Tags: python, docker

I have a python script that uses docker library to run npm i. The command is npm i, the command is as folows:

```
    response = docker.from_env().containers.run(
    image="node:12",
    entrypoint="bash",
    volumes={cur_dir: {"bind": "/var/task/install_dir/", "mode": "rw"}},
    detach=False,
    name="container_name,
    stdout=True,
    stderr=True,
    remove=True, 
    working_dir="/var/task/install_dir",
    command="-c 'npm i --prefix some/file/path' ",
)
```

I am consistently getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
raise err
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 394, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 234, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 950, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 200, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fcd9428c5b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
        resp = conn.urlopen(
      File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
        retries = retries.increment(
      File "/var/lang/lib/python3.8/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 573, in increment
        raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=2375): Max retries exceeded with url: /version (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fcd9428c5b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I'm not sure what I should or can change within bitbucket to fix this error?

Comment: Can you show us the whole script? The python you've posted in your question is incomplete

Comment: From your code example it's not obvious to me where `urllib3` is being used. Please help to share it completely

Comment: And server hostname by default it'll be `127.0.0.0` try to switch that to `0.0.0.0`

Comment: The connection to `http://localhost:2375` in the very last line of the error message sounds like incorrect configuration on how to talk to Docker; how do you have that set up?  Often you'd run lines like `npm install` inside an image's Dockerfile, if you needed to add Docker as an additional layer in your build process.

Comment: @DavidMaze you're correct, I figured out that in my pipeline definition, I forgot to add         "services: - docker" to the yaml.

Answer (score 1):

bitbucket-pipelines.yaml was not configured correctly. Needed to add the following to the step:

```
services:
      - docker
```

Answer (score 0):

In settings By default server hostname will be `127.0.0.0` and change it to `0.0.0.0` which worked for me.